# $_FILES['file']['size'] echoing 0(zero) for files over upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, error-handling, file-upload, max-size

The problem is that I want to check if the file is too large to upload so that I can display a relevant error message, but when the file is larger than upload_max_filesize in php.ini it seems to be only displaying a 0.

Why is this happening? How can I test that the file is too large to give a relevant error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Relevant excerpt:

> Since PHP 4.2.0, PHP returns an
>   appropriate error code along with the
>   file array. The error code can be
>   found in the error segment of the file
>   array that is created during the file
>   upload by PHP. In other words, the
>   error might be found in
>   $_FILES['userfile']['error'].
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_OK Value: 0; There is no
>   error, the file uploaded with success.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE Value: 1; The
>   uploaded file exceeds the
>   upload_max_filesize directive in
>   php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

the fact that the file is present and saying 0 indicates that an error occurred... usually it's over the filesize limit. <strike>That's the relevant error</strike>.

edit: As the commenter below mentions, the relevant error is on $_FILES['userfile']['error'].